# Unable to like a tweet with using Tweepy and Twitter/X v2 API

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to implement a simple twitter bot using v2 of twitter's API, I can create a tweet, but I get this error when I try to like one
[image]

I have my account set to read-write as seen below
[image]

I've even had to revoke and generate my credentials three times now, but I'm still unable to like a tweet, please I need help guys. Here is my script

```py
import tweepy

API_KEY = "API_KEY"
API_SECRET = "API_SECRET"
BEARER_TOKEN = "BEARER_TOKEN"

ACCESS_TOKEN = "ACCESS_TOKEN"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET"

client = tweepy.Client(
    BEARER_TOKEN,
    API_KEY,
    API_SECRET,
    ACCESS_TOKEN,
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)

client.create_tweet(text = "Hello, world!")
# client.like(tweet_id="1772016568446095848")
```

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to tweet with an "application only" token?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but as seen from the screenshot shared, the type of app is a web app

Comment: There are "application only" tokens that are okay for e.g. fetching X API data via GET requests and then there are API operations that are done as a "user" that could (I believe) be your own developer account/application or another X user account that authorizes your app to act on behalf of them. Posting a post (tweeting a tweet) is one of the operations that are done "as a user" and need something else than just an "application only" token. There's more info in X (Twitter) API documentation.

Comment: Just read through the documentation, apparently Twiiter/X only allows free account to create tweets, to be able to like and perform other actions you need to upgrade to a paid account.